# Convert to Conjunctive Normal Form exercise

Tags: logic, conjunctive-normal-form

I got confused in some exercises I need to convert the following to CNF step by step(I need to prove it with logical equivalence)

> $1.¬(((a→b)→a)→a)$
>   $2.¬((p→(q→r)))→((p→q)→(p→r))$

Comment: What rules you can use, and what you had tried, by the way it's a tautology $\dots$ you can use truth table method, or you want to prove it's a tautology use logical equivalence or 
natural deduction or any other valid methods $?$

Comment: I just learned them and I tried so many times but I can't convert them because i am getting confused with so many negation out of parenthesis in demorgan step I don't need truth tables for example

(¬p → q) → (q → ¬r)  

Propositional Logic
Solution.
≡  ¬(¬p → q) ∨ (q → ¬r)
≡  ¬(p ∨ q) ∨ (¬q ∨ ¬r)
≡  (¬p ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬q ∨ ¬r) 
≡  (¬p ∨ ¬q ∨ ¬r) ∧ (¬q ∨ ¬r)

Comment: I see $\dots$ so you want to prove it with logical equivalence, did you missed an 'and' in your expression:$$ ¬(((a→b)→a)→a)\color{orange}\land¬((p→(q→r)))→((p→q)→(p→r))$$

Comment: Sorry for my bad syntax I am new here... they are 2 different exercises

Comment: Should I wait? I would be really thankful if you could help

Comment: i'm working on it

Comment: thank you man its 3:30 in the morning here thats why I am asking :p I didn't know you were still here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Logical equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) we have:
\begin{align}
&¬(((a→b)→a)→a)\\
&\equiv\neg(\neg(\neg(\neg a \lor b)\lor a)\lor a)\tag*{Conditional equivalence}\\
&\equiv((a \land\neg b)\lor a)\land\neg a\tag*{De Morgan's law}\\
&\equiv((a\lor a) \land(\neg b\lor a))\land\neg a\tag*{Distributive law}\\
&\equiv(a \land(\neg b\lor a))\land\neg a\tag*{Idempotent law}\\
&\equiv((\neg b\lor a)\land a)\land\neg a\tag*{Commutative law}\\
&\equiv(\neg b\lor a)\land(a\land\neg a)\tag*{Associative law}\\
&\equiv(\neg b\lor a)\land\bot\tag*{Negation law}\\
&\equiv\bot\tag*{Identity law}\\
\\
&¬((p→(q→r)))→((p→q)→(p→r))\\
&\equiv(\neg p\lor(\neg q\lor r))\tag*{Conditional equivalence}\\
&\lor(\neg(\neg p\lor q)\lor(\neg p\lor r))\\
&\equiv(\neg p\lor(\neg q\lor r))\tag*{De Morgan's law}\\
&\lor((p\land\neg q)\lor(\neg p\lor r))\\
&\equiv(\neg p\lor(\neg q\lor r))\tag*{Distributive law}\\
&\lor((p\lor(\neg p\lor r))\land(\neg q\lor(\neg p\lor r)))\\
&\equiv(\neg p\lor(\neg q\lor r))\tag*{Associative law}\\
&\lor(((p\lor\neg p)\lor r)\land(\neg q\lor(\neg p\lor r)))\\
&\equiv(\neg p\lor(\neg q\lor r))\tag*{ Negation law}\\
&\lor((\top\lor r)\land(\neg q\lor(\neg p\lor r)))\\
&\equiv(\neg p\lor(\neg q\lor r))\tag*{Domination law}\\
&\lor(\top\land(\neg q\lor(\neg p\lor r)))\\
&\equiv(\neg p\lor(\neg q\lor r))\lor(\neg q\lor(\neg p\lor r))\tag*{Identity law}\\
&\equiv((\neg p\lor\neg q)\lor r)\lor((\neg q\lor\neg p)\lor r)\tag*{Associative law}\\
&\equiv((\neg p\lor\neg q)\lor r)\lor((\neg p\lor\neg q)\lor r)\tag*{Commutative law}\\
&\equiv(\neg p\lor\neg q)\lor r\tag*{Idempotent law}\\
\end{align}

Hence $(1)$ has $\bot$ as its minimal CNF & DNF, and $(2)$ has $(\neg p\lor\neg q)\lor r$ as its minimal CNF & DNF

Comment: really thank you, I will try to understand it now because I really messed up with the negations and parenthesis

Comment: Manx correct me if I am wrong in the second exercise the 4rth equals its Associative law, after distributive?
also I haven't done the negation law and identity law

Comment: @HellfireWorld you are right, the distributive law is a typo, was trying to copy the previous line, but forgot to change the tag, thanks

Comment: nice they haven't learned me the identity law and negation law with  ⊤  ⊥ is it correct to skip those steps in the second ? and in the first one should i let it  ≡(¬b∨a)∧(a∧¬a)

Comment: @HellfireWorld If you have rules like $(p\lor \neg p)\land q\equiv q$, you can use this instead of the Identity laws, but $\top$ simply stand for true and $\bot$ for false, and $(¬b∨a)∧(a∧¬a)$ is in CNF form, but not in minimal CNF form, since it can still be simplify further.

Comment: nice and one last question in the 2nd exercises where does the r goes? in 5th-6th equals ⊤∧  ??

Comment: @HellfireWorld by Domination law we have $\top\lor r\equiv \top$

Comment: I don't know Domination law :P ok now all make sense, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome $\overset{.~.}{\smile}$